# ASP.NET MVC/VS: How to stop VS inserting automatic IDs in pasted view content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Is there any way to stop VS (specifically 2008) automatically inserting WebForms Ids in `<asp:` elements when pasting code into a view?

E.g. by default pasting this into a view:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Results, annoyingly, in this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Miscellaneous > Auto ID elements on paste in Source view